# Switch language remaining on the same page

Tags: php, multilingual

I have another question about LANGUAGE switching... I've searched a solution but I did not find it, so here I am...

I have this code to switching language on my website (thanks to your help!!):

```
<?php if($lang['LINGUA'] != 'Italiano') { ?>
   <li><a href="index.php?lang=it"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/it.png" alt="Italiano"> Italiano</a>
   <?php } if($lang['LINGUA'] != 'Francais') { ?>
       <li><a href="index.php?lang=fr"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/fr.png" alt="Francais"> Fran&ccedil;ais</a></li>
    <?php } if($lang['LINGUA'] != 'English') { ?>
       <li><a href="index.php?lang=en"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/en.png" alt="English"> English</a></li>
 <?php } ?>
```

Now suppose I am on the "contact" page in Italian and I switch to English. The site returns me on the homepage, in English. I would like, instead, that it remains on the contact page.

Is that possible in any way..?
It is possible to switch language on one page remaining on that same page?

Secondly, the url of the page remains always, for every language (for example)
www.mysite.it/contact.php
Is it possible to specify the language in the url, for every page?

I hope I was clear enough in my questions...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Francesca

Comment: this `index.php?lang=en` would become something like `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?lang=en`

Comment: You should learn a bit more on urls and what you do in your copied code. For example you can see the link you switch to right in your code snippet above. Change it there according to each page, or better yet, use a relative path without the part before the '?'. In any case please try a bit more and checkout a few tutorials before you ask for a solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php if($lang['LINGUA'] != 'Italiano') { ?>
   <li><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?lang=it"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/it.png" alt="Italiano"> Italiano</a>
   <?php } if($lang['LINGUA'] != 'Francais') { ?>
       <li><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?lang=fr"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/fr.png" alt="Francais"> Fran&ccedil;ais</a></li>
    <?php } if($lang['LINGUA'] != 'English') { ?>
       <li><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?lang=en"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/en.png" alt="English"> English</a></li>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I know "I should learn a bit more on urls", I should still learn a lot of things, actually...! :) Anyway, thank you all for your help. This last solution of "user2211216" is perfect and does exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!!

Comment: if you liked the answer please accept it ass correct thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Just do the menu associations, you need to do for each menu.. and It would work as expected